# unable to see Firebase performance dashboard on console

Tags: firebase, firebase-performance

I have recently added firebase performance to my android app and its been 2 days I don't see any updates on firebase console. I am able to see crash, analytics on console and log cat. I also see firebase performance custom traces in log cat, however I can't see  those updated on console.
Is there anything that I am missing?

Below are the logs from the log cat:

> 06-16 07:07:33.511  2325  3121 I FirebasePerformance: Logging
>   TraceMetric - test_trace 1678ms 06-16 07:08:13.726  2325  2325 D
>   FirebasePerformance: onActivityStopped _fs:63836414 06-16 07:08:13.776
>   2325  3787 I FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric - _fs 63836ms
>   06-16 07:08:16.999  2325  2325 D FirebasePerformance:
>   onActivityResumed _bs:3272685 06-16 07:08:16.999  2325  3787 I
>   FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric - _bs 3272ms 06-16
>   07:08:47.439  2325  2325 D FirebasePerformance: onActivityStopped
>   _fs:30441313 06-16 07:08:47.443  2325  4259 I FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric - _fs 30441ms 06-16 07:20:28.401  2325  2325 D
>   FirebasePerformance: onActivityResumed _bs:700961680 06-16
>   07:20:28.414  2325 13828 I FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric -
>   _bs 700961ms 06-16 07:20:31.903  2325  2325 D FirebasePerformance: onActivityStopped _fs:3486772 06-16 07:20:31.909  2325 13828 I
>   FirebasePerformance: Logging TraceMetric - _fs 3486ms

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to see new data within about 12 hours. Please double check that the time range selected on the console covers the range when you expect the data to appear. Also check if you have pulled in latest SDK.

If you still do not see your data, you should reach out to Firebase support [firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting) with application's package name and time and type of expected data.