# Firebase performance - screen rendering is not captured on dashboard (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-performance

I have integrated Firebase in my iOS app.
I have installed Performance SDK as well and it's tracking default things like Network metrics, app start traces etc.
But, there's no data for screen wise rendering.

What could be possible reason?
My Firebase Performance SDK version is **4.10.1**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666860/how-to-integrate-firebase-performance-monitoring-in-android

Comment: Possilble duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591815/unable-to-see-firebase-performance-dashboard-on-console

Answer (score 0):

Communicated to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/) and got immediate reply from them. 
Sorted this out by updating Firebase to latest version. I was using Firebase 4.x.x and Screen Rendering Performance feature is added in 5.x.x